# User Profile replicable field not showing data from user

Tags: user-profile, lookup-column, user-profile-property, replication

We have created a custom user profile field called "X" and checked the box for replicate and alias and ran a full profile sync.

The field "X" appears in the drop down list for field to show when you create a custom column in a list for type 'people or group'.

We create a new column called "Get X" to the list.

We have verified that "X" has over 900 users with that data and data.

Going back to the list to create a new entry and we put the value in for "X" that matches a user, we are getting no results found.